# IE6 jquery unable to update select tag options w/ .append

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6, append, html-select

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        function getcsa(){
            $.get("getcsas.php",{},function(xml){
                $(xml).find('csa').each(function(){
                    var csa = $(this);
                    var vzid = $(csa).find('vzid').text();
                    var firstname = $(csa).find('firstname').text();
                    var lastname = $(csa).find('lastname').text();
                    var option = '<option value="' + vzid + '">'+lastname+', '+firstname+'</option>';
                    $("#agent").append(option);
                });
            });
        };
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            getcsa();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <select id="agent">
    </select>
</body>
```

The above generates a populated dropdown list in FF but not IE6...

Comment: I see you never got a legitimate answer that works in IE6. I'm in the same boat on this same question, where .append() won't work with IE6 on a SELECT, but also am unfortunate in that I don't have a way to test IE6 without forking out a bunch of cash.

Answer (score 1):

Are you really expecting XML?  Perhaps, you should set that as your expected data type on the get call.

```
 $.get("getcsas.php",{},function(xml){
      $(xml).find('csa').each(function(){
          var csa = $(this);
          var vzid = $(csa).find('vzid').text();
          var firstname = $(csa).find('firstname').text();
          var lastname = $(csa).find('lastname').text();
          var option = '<option value="' + vzid + '">'+lastname+', '+firstname+'</option>';
          $("#agent").append(option);
      }, 'xml' );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Came back from vacation and found the trouble.

I added

```
header ("content-type: text/xml");
```

to the top of the getcsas.php file and all started working like a charm.